# HIVE - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space - with hive table more than 700 columns

Tags: java, hive

I have a hive external textfile table(table name:tmp) with about 700 columns.
when i tried to create a inner orc table(table name:inner_table,) with a command `" insert into table inner_table select * from tmp;"`.

I got a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error.

I have done a similar task with 50 columns.
but this time with 700 columns, I failed.

I have already set these properties below. but still not worked out.

```
--set mapreduce.map.memory.mb=8000;

--set mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx8000m;

--set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=8000;

--set mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx8000m;
```

could someone helps me with this problem please.
thanks

tmp:

```
create external table tmp(
col_1 string,
.
.
.
col_700 string
)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
null defined as '\\N'
stored as textfile
location 'hdfs://fin:8020/data/raw/2018/03/16/06';
```

inner_table:

```
create table inner_talble(
col_1 string,
.
.
.
col_700 string
)
clustered by (col_1)
sorted by (col_1)
into 30 buckets
stored as orc;
```

command:

```
hive> insert into table inner_table select * from tmp;
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: please check the content i updated, thanks.